Mobile data is not connected on Android 13
Mobile data is active but cannot be connected.
To solve this issue, I checked the log as below.

TelephonyNetworkFactory[0]  
    onNeedNetworkFor [NetworkRequest
[ REQUEST id=45,
 [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10072 RequestorUid: 1000 RequestorPkg: android UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ], mPriority=20, state=UNSATISFIED, mAttachedDataNetwork=null, isMetered=true, created time=16:35:27.169, evaluation result=null]
 shouldApply false

ConnectivityService     requestNetwork for uid/pid:1000/1134 
asUid: 10116 activeRequest: 
null callbackRequest: 46 
[NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=47, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10116 RequestorUid: 1000 RequestorPkg: android UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]] 
callback flags: 0 order: 2147483647

ConnectivityService     
NetworkReassignment : no changes

I believe the requested network information was ignored by connectivityService.
In the ConnectivityService.computeNetworkResolution function, I think the best network is judged by IMS, not INTERNET.
DEBUG LOG:
ConnectivityService     test bestNetwork :
 NetworkAgentInfo{network{100}  handle{432902426637}  ni{MOBILE[LTE] CONNECTED extra: IMS} 
Score(45 ; KeepConnected : 0 ; 
Policies : EVER_VALIDATED_NOT_AVOIDED_WHEN_BAD&IS_VALIDATED)  created everValidated lastValidated  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data1 LinkAddresses: [ 2001:4200:500:f3f8:d8eb:b9ff:fec8:b9da/64 ] 
DnsAddresses: [ /2001:4200:110:1000:504::21,/2001:4200:210:1000:504::21 ] 
PcscfAddresses: [ /2001:4200:110:1000:721::11,/2001:4200:210:1000:721::11 ] 
Domains: null MTU: 1500 
TcpBufferSizes: 4096,6291456,12582912,4096,1048576,2097152 
Routes: [ ::/0 -> fe80::6cea:20f3:1a01:65e3 rmnet_data1 mtu 1500,2001:4200:500:f3f8::/64 -> :: rmnet_data1 mtu 0 ]}} 
 nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: MMS&IMS&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED&MMTEL 
LinkUpBandwidth>=14Kbps
 LinkDnBandwidth>=14Kbps 
Specifier: <TelephonyNetworkSpecifier 
[mSubId = 1]> SubscriptionIds: {1} 

UnderlyingNetworks: Null]}  factorySerialNumber=6}

Shouldn't IMS be excluded when looking for the best network?
How can I solve this issue?
